# How to get the directory location of The Window in Focus in Python

Tags: python, windows, directory, path, filepath

I would like to know how to get the path of the current window which is in focus.

I am writing a script which is waiting for a specific key-combination and when that combination is pressed, I would like the script to get the path of the window in focus.

This is what I have for now.

To get the name of the window in  focus:

```
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow, GetWindowText

print(GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow()))
```

This returns the name of the folder that is open: `TestFolder`

But how do I get the path of that folder? For instance, that folder in question is on my desktop.

> TestFolder -- D:\GM\System Folders\Desktop\TestFolder

How do I get that location through code in Python?

Comment: Where are the functions `GetWindowText` and `GetForegroundWindow` from?

Comment: @mkrieger1   win32gui. Sorry, forgot to add it. Have updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me if you are asking about the .exe path of any process or if you are asking about the path a File Explorer window has navigated to.

Any .exe:

1. Call `GetForegroundWindow` to get the window handle.
2. Call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get the process id of the process that owns the window.
3. Call `OpenProcess` to open a handle to the process.
4. Call `QueryFullProcessImageName` to get the path.
5. Close the handle with `CloseHandle`.

To get the path a Explorer window has navigated to you must use the `IShellWindows` COM interface to enumerate the open windows and use the returned browser interface to get the window handle for each window and compare that with `GetForegroundWindow`. A C++ example of enumerating can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040720-00/?p=38393). That blog post also shows how you get the path from the browser object.

Comment: I am asking for the 'path a File Explorer Window' is currently on. Suppose, the current focus is on windows explorer and it is showing "D:\GM\System Folders\Desktop\TestFolder", I would like to know how can I get it via code in python. I am new to this so can't really understand C++ yet. Examples in python would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate over all the Explorer windows and find if there is one in foreground, and if so, get its path.
Thanks to this answer to which I've added minor details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73181850/8582902.

```
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow
from win32com import client
from urllib.parse import unquote
from pythoncom import CoInitialize

fore_window_hwnd = GetForegroundWindow()
CoInitialize()
shell = client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
fore_window_path = None
for window in shell.Windows():
    if window.hwnd != fore_window_hwnd: continue
    fore_window_path = unquote(window.LocationURL[len("file:///"):])
    break
if fore_window_path: msg = f'Path of the foreground window: {fore_window_path}'
else: msg = 'Could not find an explorer window that is in foregroud.'
```