# How to get path from filedialog currently open

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program which requires to get path from already open File Explorer / filedialog.

For example, I have opened some folder in File Explorer. It may downloads folder, program files folder or even desktop. Now I want to run a Python file and get the full path to the folder which is being displayed on the screen. For **downloads** folder, it should return `C:\Users\User123\Downloads` or if **Program Files** folder is open, `C:\Program Files`.

I tried reading,

1. [How to get the current file type at filedialog in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65907004/how-to-get-the-current-file-type-at-filedialog-in-tkinter)
2. [Get full path of currently open files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899574/get-full-path-of-currently-open-files)
3. [Python - How to check if a file is used by another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589407/python-how-to-check-if-a-file-is-used-by-another-application)

I even tried searching online. But none of them work.

I want something like,

```python
import some_library

path = some_library.getPathFromFileDialogOpenedOnScreen()
print(path)
```

I am using Windows 10 - 64 bit and python 3.10

Can somebody help?
Thanks in advance.

*(For those who will ask "Why do you want to do this?", I am doing this for my college project!)* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, you can get a list of open Explorer windows using the Component Object Model (COM), like so:

```py
from win32com import client
from urllib.parse import unquote
from pythoncom import CoInitialize

CoInitialize()
shell = client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
for window in shell.Windows():
    print("Open window:", window.LocationURL)

unquoted_path = list(shell.Windows())[-1].LocationURL[len("file:///"):]
most_recently_opened_window_path = unquote(unquoted_path)

print("Most recently opened window path:", most_recently_opened_window_path)
```

Output:

```
Open window: file:///C:/Stuff
Open window: file:///C:/Program%20Files
Open window: file:///C:/Users/Todd%20Bonzalez/Downloads
Most recently opened window path: C:/Users/Todd Bonzalez/Downloads
```

I'm not that familiar with COM. It appears to return a URL encoded string with `file:///` prepended to it, so you'll need to first slice it, and then use [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) to get the proper path.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellwindows-item
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)

Comment: Thanks for answering! But, I am getting `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Import and call `pythoncom.CoInitialize()` before using `win32com`, on a per-thread basis.

Comment: Wow!!! That works!! Thanks for all the efforts you took!

Comment: No problemo. Just keep in mind this doesn't account for when no Explorer windows are open, in which case you'd get a `IndexError: list index out of range` exception. So catch that exception or break up the line starting with `unquoted_path = ` and check `if list(shell.Windows()):` before indexing into it. Lists return `False` if they are empty.

Comment: Ahh, yes! Got it!